# How to dynamically add a view to a flipper view

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
    <ViewFlipper
     android:id="@+id/flipper"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     >
     <include android:id="@+id/include1" layout="@layout/fb_list1"/>
     <include  android:id="@+id/include2" layout="@layout/fb_list2"/>
     </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main layout. I have 2 views in a flipper view  and I want to add a third one dynamically. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static final LayoutParams mLop = 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

here is your flipper view which you have to create dynamically....

```
mFlipper = new ViewFlipper(mContext);
            mFlipper.setLayoutParams(mLop);
            this.addView(mFlipper);
```

here is the view which is to be added inside flipper view

```
vm.setLayoutParams(mLop);
                mFlipper.addView(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) method should work with this. However, have you considered using a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
// this gets you the LinearLayout
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);

// Create your view and add it
ViewFlipper vf = new ViewFlipper(this);
ll.addView(vf, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```